# Is there any way to connect Firebase database with 2 projects?

Tags: android, firebase, web

I have admin panel which is web based and android app. Admin panel uploads data and android app fetch and insert data. Is it possible to do it with single Firebase database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Firebase project can service many individual applications, including any mix of Android, iOS, and web based apps.

I suggest [reading this page of documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more) for more detailed explanations of what  Firebase project really is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can connect the same database project to your web as well Android app.
Go to Firebase Console.
Select the Project or create a new one.
You will see platform options - Web, Android, iOS
Follow [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#:%7E:text=In%20the%20center%20of%20the,Enter%20your%20app%27s%20nickname.) to register the web app.
Similarly, clicking on Android will guide you to setting up on Android.

[image: Click on the supported platform to add Web/Android]

Comment: Thankyou so much it was really helpful

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped.